# Splitting a dataframe with the help of a loop (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I need help. I would like to go through a DF. Partly my users have 2 teams (separated by commas in the row). I split these by the commas and write them in the new columns Team_1 and Team_2.
If there is only one team, the name from team(s) goes into team 1.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': [
        'abby',
        'bella',
        'coco',
        'deedee',
        'elliot'],
    'email': [
        'a@test.com',
        'b@test.com',
        'c@test.com',
        'd@test.com',
        'e@test.com'],
    'team(s)': [
        'alpha',
        'omega',
        'alpha,omega',
        'beta',
        'beta,omega'
    ]})

df_split_teams = df.join(df['team(s)'].str.split(',', 1, expand=True)).rename(columns={0: 'Team_1', 1:'Team_2'})
if 'None' in df.index:
    df_split_teams['Team_1'] == df_split_teams['team(s)']
```

I can use a function to display the individual team names that are available:

```
def get_team_names(df):
    team_names = set(df['team(s)'])
    split_team_names = set()
    for team in team_names:
        for name in team.split(','):
            split_team_names.add(name)
    return split_team_names
```

But: Now I want to have a separate DF for all teams. One DF per team. Best automated with a loop. First of all I did it like this:

```
df_alpha = df_split_teams[(df_split_teams['Team_1'].isin(['alpha'])) | (df_split_teams['Team_2'].isin(['alpha']))]
df_beta = df_split_teams[(df_split_teams['Team_1'].isin(['beta'])) | (df_split_teams['Team_2'].isin(['beta']))]
df_omega = df_split_teams[(df_split_teams['Team_1'].isin(['omega'])) | (df_split_teams['Team_2'].isin(['omega']))]
```

but new teams are added from time to time or we have different teams. The code should be generally valid. Also for others from my collegues. Therefore, I cannot predefine the team names in my code.

Hope you can help.
Regards
Bayquiri

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to solution.

You just need to iterate through your function `get_team_names()` using `globals()` method.

The `globals()` method returns the dictionary of the current global symbol table.
*(A symbol table is a data structure maintained by a compiler)*

```
for i in get_team_names(df):
    globals()['df_' + str(i)] = df_split_teams[(df_split_teams['Team_1'].isin([i])) | (df_split_teams['Team_2'].isin([i]))]
```

output:

```
df_alpha
Out[29]: 
   name       email      team(s) Team_1 Team_2
0  abby  a@test.com        alpha  alpha   None
2  coco  c@test.com  alpha,omega  alpha  omega

df_beta
Out[30]: 
     name       email     team(s) Team_1 Team_2
3  deedee  d@test.com        beta   beta   None
4  elliot  e@test.com  beta,omega   beta  omega

df_omega
Out[31]: 
     name       email      team(s) Team_1 Team_2
1   bella  b@test.com        omega  omega   None
2    coco  c@test.com  alpha,omega  alpha  omega
4  elliot  e@test.com   beta,omega   beta  omega
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! But now i have another problem :( 
In my source code I have spaces in the team names. 'df_' + str(i) does not convert well with this. Can I take the spaces out directly? Or should I clean that up first?

Comment: replace spaces with underscores.... globals()['df_' + str(i.replace(" ", "_"))] = ..............